# React Native - How to implement modal on a view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

As per title, I would like to have a modal opened when clicked on a view

**app.js**

```
<View>
    <MediaBar onClick={this.toggleModal}> />

      <Modal show={this.state.isOpen}
      onClose={this.toggleModal}>
      `Here's some content for the modal`
    </Modal>
 </View>
```

Mediabar.js: https://pastebin.com/6bW5gz99

modal.js: https://pastebin.com/3vQgLyTg

Answer (score 1):

The Modal component has a `visible` property.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

You just have to update its value using your parent component state.

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Modal, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={this.styles.viewStyle}>
        <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible} 
            transparent={true}>
            <View style={this.styles.viewStyle}>
              <View style={this.styles.dialogStyle}>
              </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
        <View style={this.styles.anotherView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setState({ modalVisible: true})}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  styles = {
    viewStyle: {
      flex:1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    dialogStyle: {
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height*0.2,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width*0.9,
      backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
      elevation: 10,
      borderRadius: 5
    },
    anotherView:{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }
  }


}



export default App;
```

To Achieve the modal like below:

[image: Modal View OnClick]

Comment: Where does my Mediabar goes or placed at?

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about where your media bar goes in the code you provided. You can place it on `styles.anotherView` if that is what is opening the modal.

Comment: The Mediabar is a view for a button (Using an image), it is configured in Mediabar.js and called in app.js